# Is performance affected on local server?

Tags: performance

I have my drupal on a server that doesnt have access to internet.

Does this hurt the preformance?

I am getting this error on the status report :

> "HTTP request status  Fails"

If it does, how can I overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up Drupal on your local machine without an Internet connection, where you can do most of your development work. See this [post on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/157602) for info about setting this up properly. You shouldn't be getting any HTTP errors, I'd check to make sure you don't have any some external images, files or other resources (like feeds) embedded which would require the browser to fetch from www.